# From observableArrayList to ObservableArrayList<PieChart.Data>

Tags: java, javafx

It could be that I am approaching this problem wrong.. But I would like to visualise the data in my tableview in different visualisation types , for example PieChart and BarChart.

How can this be approached? I for example try to use my observableArrayList in my PieChart, but I can't get it to work.

I currently have:

```
ObservableList data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ObservableList<PieChart.Data> dataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

The point is( and the reason I don't use a data class) is because the user should be able to choose what data that gets in the table view, and visualized. That's the reason I use the dynamically rows and column.

To clarify: the main point with the application is for the user to connect to a database and select which data he wants visualized. So with other words, the user selects for example two columns in the table view and clicks piechart, then I want the piechart to appear.

Comment: Show us some code, but what you want to do is something like this: ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(YourObservableArrayList);

Comment: I tried that too, but I get an InvocationTargetException

Comment: You need to clarify this. What exactly are you displaying in the table? What exactly are you displaying in the Pie Chart (or Bar Chart)? How are you defining the relationship between rows in the table and values in the pie chart?

Comment: The user should be able to decide for himself. The table view connects to a database and the user filters the data and selects the columns he want to visualize in for example a piechart.

Answer (score 1):

Data in a `PieChart` needs two attributes: a name (`String`) and a value (`double`). A `BarChart` is similar.

So, assuming you are using some arbitrary data structure (such as a `List<String>`) for the data displayed in each row in the `TableView`, you will need to store the user's choice of which column has the name of the data, and which has the value.

For each element in the `TableView`'s list of items, you will need to map that `item` to a `new PieChart.Data(name, value)`, and use those to populate an `ObservableList<PieChart.Data>` to pass to the `PieChart`:

```
int userChosenDataNameColumnIndex ;
int userChosenDataValueColumnIndex ;

// for each List<String> in the table's data:
List<String> rowData ;
String name = rowData.get(userChosenDataNameColumnIndex);
double value = Double.parseDouble(rowData.get(userChosenDataValueColumnIndex));
PieChart.Data pieChartData = new PieChart.Data(name, value);
```

You can manage all this by hand:

```
TableView<List<String>> table = new TableView<>();
ObservableList<List<String>> tableData = loadTableDataFromDatabase();
int userChosenDataNameColumnIndex ;
int userChosenDataValueColumnIndex ;

ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
for (List<String> rowData : tableData) {
    String name = rowData.get(userChosenDataNameColumnIndex);
    double value = Double.parseDouble(rowData.get(userChosenDataValueColumnIndex));
    pieChartData.add(new PieChart.Data(name, value));
}
PieChart pieChart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
```

Note that this just creates a pie chart that is a snapshot of the data in the table. If you add rows to the table, or delete rows from the table, the pie chart will not update. You can use the [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) framework to create an `ObservableList<PieChart.Data>` that is a "live" view of the table data:

```
TableView<List<String>> table = new TableView<>();
ObservableList<List<String>> tableData = loadTableDataFromDatabase();
int userChosenDataNameColumnIndex ;
int userChosenDataValueColumnIndex ;

ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = EasyBind.map(tableData, rowData -> {
    String name = rowData.get(userChosenDataNameColumnIndex);
    double value = Double.parseDouble(rowData.get(userChosenDataValueColumnIndex));
    return new PieChart.Data(name, value);
});
PieChart pieChart = new PieChart(pieChartData);

ObservableList<XYChart.Data<String, Number>> barChartData = EasyBind.map(tableData, rowData -> {
    String name = rowData.get(userChosenDataNameColumnIndex);
    Double value = new Double(rowData.get(userChosenDataValueColumnIndex));
    return new XYChart.Data(name, value);
});
BarChart<String, Number> barChart = new BarChart<>(new CategoryAxis(), new NumberAxis(), barChartData)
```

Comment: Sorry.. contrived to post this before I finished it. It's now complete.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! When I have received the Columns the user has selected, would you recommend pulling that particular data from the database and into a piechart, or to pull the data from the tableview  ? If so - is there any way to get all data in just one column?

Comment: Pull the data from the `TableView`, using the techniques I showed in the answer; that will get all the data from the column specified.

Comment: What is the "list" in the easy bind ? Also, I don't have the column indexes but the Columns itself. I use a checkbox to get the Table Column object.

And by the way - my tableView is just an ObservableList = FXCollection.observableArrayList()

Comment: and by the way, I tested with the by hand method,by entering manual indexes - that worked great

Comment: `list` should have been `rowData`: now fixed. I recommend properly typing your `ObservableList`s (i.e. `ObservableList<SomeType>`, not `ObservableList`. All this will become a lot clearer to you if you do that. Your compiler and/or IDE should be giving all sorts of warnings if you don't do this.

Comment: Thank you, will try it out. Any tips on how I can get column index when I have the TableColumn?

Comment: To add to my previous comment : I've made checkboxes on each TableColumn, if one column is checked, I get the whole TableColumn. From that I can for example run a getText to get the name of the column .

Comment: I get an null pointer when setting the pieChartData to the piechart. Did an iteration through the pieChartData, and it looks perfect:" Data[Ole,100.0]".. Cant understand why I get an null pointer when i do pieChart.setData(pieChartData)

Comment: Fixed it, you need to add FX collections  ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData
                = FXCollections.observableArrayList(EasyBind.map(dataen, rowData -> ....